# Binary Search Tree in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have the following code to insert in the bst however, it fails to insert all the nodes except for the root. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node* right;
    Node* left;
    Node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
    }
    Node() {}
};

class BST
{
public:
    Node* head;
    void insert(int data)
    {
        if (head == nullptr)
        {
            head = new Node(data);
            head->data = data;
        }
        else
        {
            // head = new Node(data);
            insertNode(data, head);
        }
    }

    void insertNode(int data, Node* head)
    {
        if (head == nullptr)
        {
            head = new Node(data);
            return;
        }
        if (head)
        {
            Node* temp = head;
            if (temp->data > data)
            {
                insertNode(data, temp->left);
            }
            else if (temp->data <= data)
                insertNode(data, temp->right);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insertNode()` takes a copy of the pointer, so changes made inside the function have no effect on the actual pointer in the tree. What you want to do is take a reference to the pointer:

```
void insertNode(int data, Node*& head)
```

Comment: thanks it works now. But is this the right way of writing insert function?

Comment: @OmarHashmi Not quite. Your conditions in the `insertNode` method are misplaced. If the value is less than (or equal to) `data` then you should be inserting in the left subtree, otherwise the right subtree. Read Jason's answer as well.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Does it really matter whether he inserts to the left or the right when the value is equal?  Either will work just as well.. as long as the choice is consistent throughout the implementation.

Comment: @Dmitri [The definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) of a binary search tree is one where any node is greater than its left tree and less than its right tree.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That definition doesn't allow for inserting *at all* when the keys are equal (no duplicates).  But when duplicate keys *are* allowed, either side works.

Answer (score 5):

The parameter `head` in insertNode shadows the member variable named `head`.

However, while that's a really bad practice, the other answer is the true reason for your error, so please select his answer instead (once you get it working, of course).

I'd recommend changing the signature of `insertNode` to

```
void insertNode(int data, Node*& node)
```

Also, you don't need to check for `head == nullptr` in insert.  You have a duplicate check in `insertNode`

So insert could look like this:

```
void insert(data) {
    insertNode(data, head);
}
```

Finally, you're not initializing head within the constructor.  It's possible that head will be initialized to something other than nullptr, especially if you compile this in release mode.  Add a constructor like this:

```
BST() : head(nullptr) {
    // Other init stuff here if necessary
}
```

You'll also want to make `Node* head` a private data member instead of public.

Answer (score 0):

In your function " insertNode" you are using if(head) , this if will work only if head == 1 , and head is never equals to 1 because its a pointer  , so this "if" is not working.!